# Windows Server cmd returns immediately, but program keeps running

Tags: c#, windows, windows-server-2012

I made a C# program. If I run it in debug mode in Visual Studio, it keeps running for several minutes and produces output to standard out. But when I build it for release and run it from the command line (cmd), then it is run as a background process, or something. It looks like the program returns immediately, but it is in fact running in the background. But I want to see the output. I have not seen this before in Windows. This is Windows Server 2012. What could be wrong?

Comment: Well we don't know anything about what your program does, which makes it hard to tell. We don't even know whether it's configured as a console app or something else.

Comment: It's probably just that the program terminates. When you have the debugger attaches, it waits before closing the console window. Otherwise, in release builds, the console window closes immediately upon termination and you never see anything. If you want more than speculation, post repro code.

Comment: Check the SubSystem setting under Linker/System.  Perhaps the debug config has this set to Console and the release config has it set to Windows.